# Blocking certain ip's if exceeds 'tries per x'

Tags: python

Having a server that has to handle lots of TCP-requests from gprs-modules I think it is handy to set up something to protect this server from multiple requests from certain ip's.

Now I want to make something(within python) that will check how much times a certain ip tries to connect and if this exceeds a given amount of tries this ip will be blocked for a given amount of time (or forever).

I am wondering if there are libraries present to do this, or how I should tackle this problem in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't tackle this from your code - this is what a firewall is designed to do.

Using iptables its trivial:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 2 -j DROP
```

The above means "drop anything that makes more than 2 connection attempts in 10 minutes at port $PORT"

Comment: Will using python to tackle this issue decrease the speed of 'dropping' the connections a lot?

Comment: Yes, it will; but why would you want to do it in Python? Its unnecessary overhead. If you cannot control the clients, then you don't want to create your own "firewall" in Python to solve this problem. It won't be fast, and you are re-inventing a wheel.

Comment: Would be fancy to send an email or a whatsapp whenever someone tries attacks the server to the owner of the server :)

Comment: Thankyou, I will then use this approach

Answer (score 2):

If you decide you do want to handle this in code, you don't *need* a separate library (although using one will probably be more efficient), you can add something like the following to your connection handler:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
from datetime import datetime

floodlog = defaultdict(deque)


def checkForFlood(clientIP):
    """check if how many times clientIP has connected within TIMELIMIT, and block if more than MAX_CONNECTEIONS_PER_TIMELIMIT"""

    now = datetime.now()
    clientFloodLog = floodlog[clientIP]
    clientFloodLog.append(now)
    if len(clientFloodLog) > MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_TIMELIMIT:
        earliestLoggedConenction = clientFloodLog.popleft()
        if now - earliestLoggedConnection < TIMELIMIT:
            blockIP(clientIP)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Burhan Khalid said. You don't want to try this in your code. It's not very performant and that's what firewalls are made for.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 2 -j DROP
```

This example is very usefull but not very handy. The problem is that you're also limiting good/trusted connections.

You need to be more flexible. On a linux-based OS you can use fail2ban. It's a very handy tool to prevent your services of bruteforce attacks by using dynamic iptables rules. On Debian/Ubuntu you can install it by using apt-get. If you're on CentOS you need to use a third party repository.

1. Log every connection into a logfile:

   > ```
   > [Jun 3 03:52:23] server [pid]: Connect from 1.2.3.4
   > [Jun 3 03:52:23] server [pid]: Failed password for $USER from 1.2.3.4 port $DST
   > [Jun 3 03:52:23] server [pid]: Connect from 2.3.4.5
   > [Jun 3 03:52:23] server [pid]: Successful login from 2.3.4.5
   > ```
2. Now monitor this file with fail2ban and define a regex to difference between successful and failed logins. Tell fail2ban how long it should block the IP for you and if you would like to get an email notification.

The documentation is very good so have a look onto here how you have to configure fail2ban to monitor your logile: [fail2ban docu](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters)

You don't have to watch only for failed logins. You can also try to watch out for portscans. And the biggest win: don't only secure your application. Safe also your SSH, HTTP, etc logins for beeing bruteforced! ;)

Answer (score 1):

For a pure Python solution, I think you could reuse something I developed for the same problem, but for the client point of view: avoiding to issue more than 'x tries per sec' to a service provider.

The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/icecrime/RateLimiting): you can probably reuse most of it, but you'll need to replace the `time.sleep` call for your 'blacklisting' mechanism.